# Can't access TextBox.Text in Background worker

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a winforms application that was originally designed to be have different sequential functions triggered manually with buttons (4 buttons without corresponding backgroundworkers,4 buttons with corresponding backgroundworkers, 8 buttons total). Each button does some quick set up synchronously and then fires off a background worker to do the work asynchronously. This can be heavy work.

A decision was made to have an "express" option that does all the work of the 4 buttons with default options. Unfortunately I didn't design this as modular as I should have.

What I have done is have the ExpressButton call a 5th background worker, which in turn calls InvokeOnClick on each button in sequential order. Luckily the 4 non asynchronous buttons clicks get called first. I am using an AutoResetEvent to block the 5th backgroundworker while each sequential button is clicked.

Here is some pseudo code, buttons 1-4 don't call background workers, buttons 5-8 call backgroundworkers and _resetevent = new AutoResetEvent(false) in the global variables:

```
 private void backgroundWorker5_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)    
 {
        ControlEventArgs automationcheck = new ControlEventArgs(expressButton);

        InvokeOnClick(button1, null);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        InvokeOnClick(button2, null);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        InvokeOnClick(button3, null);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        InvokeOnClick(button4, null);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        InvokeOnClick(button5, automationcheck);
        _resetevent.WaitOne();
        _resetevent.Reset();
        InvokeOnClick(button6, automationcheck);
        _resetevent.WaitOne();
        _resetevent.Reset();
        InvokeOnClick(button7, automationcheck);
        _resetevent.WaitOne();
        _resetevent.Reset();
        InvokeOnClick(button8, automationcheck);
        _resetevent.WaitOne();
        _statusBox.AppendText("Finished" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

So here is the strange thing. In the UI I have 2 textboxes where users enter information.

In backgroundworker1 (corresponding above to button5), I can access the .Text property of the first TextBox.
However in backgroundworker2 (corresponding to button6), I cannot access the .Text property of the other TextBox.
I can access it in the button6 click event all the way up until I call RunWorkerAsync().
As soon as I'm in the backgroundworker2 trying to access the TextBox.Text freezes the program up. No exception, it just stops.

Here is my theory :
backgroundworker1 is called/run with no parameters from button5 click event
backgroundworker2 is called/run with parameters from button6 click event
By passing an objectlist in RunWorkAsync(params[]) am I causing it to NOT pass some context of the original form control?
The funny thing here is that there is another textbox on the main form called statusBox that I can still access in backgroundworker2, in fact that's what I've been using for debugging purposes.

So to recap.

```
Button 9    
  Backgroundworker 5
    Button 1
    Button 2
    Button 3
    Button 4
    Button 5
      Backgroundworker 1
        Can access TextBox.Text here
    Button 6
      Backgroundworker 2
        Can't access TextBox.Text here
    Button 7
      Backgroundworker 3
         unsure
    Button 8
      Backgroundworker 4
         unsure
```

Worst case scenario :

Since button6 still has access to the textbox, I can grab the text out and pass it in the params list for runworkerasync. However I'd still like to know why 1 backgroundworker can see a textbox on the mainform and another can't.

Comment: You should use a delegate and Invoke / Invoke requried...

Comment: There are a lot of things I should probably be doing, but this question is directly related to why 1 background worker can access a textbox and another can't.

Comment: The question makes no sense. It doesn't matter if you can access (sometimes) an UI property from another thread, because by definition the behavior is **undefined**.

Comment: You cannot update UI elements from a worker, try using `dispatcher.run` to update UI elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as Austin said and Invoke() all the calls.

You're hitting this exception (i don't care if it's consistent) just randomly, any call to UI from a worker thread may lead to an exception as only the main thread must access the UI.

My bet is when you access the .Text property for the first time the control itself does not need to redraw, but the second time it needs, so you will end with a cross-threading exception.

Comment: It ended up being a variation of this. The specifics are interesting, the 2 text boxes are connection strings, the first 2 buttons attempt to autodetect and the second 2 buttons validate. When all of this was done step by step it was necessary for each validation to check if the other box was already validated. If it was, nothing was done, but if it wasn't the current click needed to set ReadOnly=false on the other box. Obviously when invoking these in order one is always going to not be validated yet, so one of the clicks turned ReadOnly=false. I think that caused the need for a redraw.

Comment: To fix it, I realized it made more sense to store the connection string in a global variable after validation then to reference the .Text property of the TextBox everytime I needed the connection string. Seems obvious now, but I'm new to the whole UI thing and this was a great mistake to make because I have a better idea of the thread infrastructure (at least in winforms)